Finding formula for $a+b+c=n$ where $(a,b,c)$ are positive integers.
I'm currently studying a book by Paul Zeitz and currently stuck on exercise 6.2.23, below is the problem:

Find a formula for the number of different ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers that satisfy $$a+b+c=n$$

For my first attempt I first started by looking at some values for $n$ like $n=50$ which by using 'Stars and Bars Technique' gets you to the solution $\binom{52}{2}$. I am wondering if the same technique could be applied to the question above so that I can obtain a formula for it.
Apologies if I am missing something elementary here.

Yes, Stars and Bars works for all $n$.  This is literally asking for the Stars and Bars solution given that you have three positive terms which sum to $n$.

Does it mean that the solution is $\binom{n+2}{2}$?

Your problem requires positive solutions, not non-negative solutions. For positive solutions, you should be getting $\binom {n-1}2$.  For $n=3$, say, the only solution is $(1,1,1)$. Your formula would give $\binom 52=10$ corresponding to the solutions $(1,1,1)$, the six permutations of $(2,1,0)$ and the $3$ permutations of $(3,0,0)$. if $0$ were allowed as a solution.

Ah I see, I should be using the $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ formula right? Thanks for clearing things up!

As a general suggestion:  always work explicit examples numerically to confirm formulas.  With this sort of question, it's usually easy to write out small examples completely.  Quick way to test formulas.

Do you see that there's a one-one correspondence between solutions of $a+b+c=n$ in positive integers and solutions of $a+b+c=n-3$ in nonnegative integers?

Here is a similar question.
